# Entity Framework 6 - Navigation Property as Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table that links two other tables together. When I import these tables into the edmx file, EF automatically creates a navigation property between the two tables and does not create a entity table for the association. Which is great and useful; however, when doing some complex joins from other various tables it would be far more effective to be able to join off of the association table to limit the number of trips to the database.

I tired a solution where I would remove a table, add the middle table, and then re-add the other table. This worked; however, when building the project I get an error:

> Error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 6123, 6490: Foreign key constraint 'fk_Um' from table UserModules (ModuleId) to table Modules (ModuleId):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side.

Is there a way to add in the association table, so I can directly join on it without going through the navigation property?

Comment: I'm assuming that this is database-first?

Comment: Yes this is database-first